# Oracle instance won't start

Tags: oracle, grid, oracle11gr2

I can't figure out a problem which has happened recently.
During maintenance windows, one of my colleagues  stopped Oracle RAC Services with database, after that we are unable to start the database.
A couple words 'bout conf:
Oracle RAC(Grid Infrastructure Patch Set Update : 11.2.0.3.4) with 2 nodes and Shared directory location which mounted from storagebox.

Problem: 
crsctl stat res -t shows that instance is STARTING, and I see one process of oracle:
oracle   16801 99.1  0.0 235416 15444 ?        Rs   03:22   8:25 oracleCRMSDB1 (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))

but nothing happens and no alerts/traces generates under ../trace dir and no other processes of oracle appear as well.

Needful information below (crsctl conf + opatch lsinventory): [info](http://pastebin.com/gxFQ9aTt)

+log of grid oraagent here: [grid_oraagent_log](http://ge.tt/429aGTo1/v/0?c)

+log of oracle oraagent: [oracle_oraagent_log](http://ge.tt/2kT6ITo1/v/0?c)

oraagent though contain this error:

2014-07-16 03:32:49.269: [    AGFW][2643461888] {1:55831:2} Created alert : (:CRSAGF00113:) :  Aborting the command: start for resource: ora.crmsdb.db 1 1
2014-07-16 03:32:49.269: [ora.crmsdb.db][2643461888] {1:55831:2} [start] (:CLSN00110:) clsn_agent::abort {
2014-07-16 03:32:49.269: [ora.crmsdb.db][2643461888] {1:55831:2} [start] abort {
2014-07-16 03:32:49.269: [ora.crmsdb.db][2643461888] {1:55831:2} [start] abort command: start
2014-07-16 03:32:49.269: [ora.crmsdb.db][2643461888] {1:55831:2} [start] tryActionLock {
2014-07-16 03:32:51.270: [ora.crmsdb.db][2643461888] {1:55831:2} [start] got lock
2014-07-16 03:32:51.270: [ora.crmsdb.db][2643461888] {1:55831:2} [start] tryActionLock }
2014-07-16 03:32:51.270: [ora.crmsdb.db][2643461888] {1:55831:2} [start] abort  }
2014-07-16 03:32:51.270: [ora.crmsdb.db][2643461888] {1:55831:2} [start] (:CLSN00110:) clsn_agent::abort }

CRS services were restarted on both nodes a few times,
Both servers were rebooted as well.

I will really appreciate any ideas or thoughts! If you need any other info, just ask.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the problem itself is not really programming related, it sounds like the quesiton may be better asked at http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: What shows the alertlog of the instance[s]?

Comment: As I mentioned in topic there are no any alerts or traces generates, that means that when I run
sql> startup nomount; 
it even does not open or tries to update the files.

Comment: Since we stuck on this and customer does not want to check or investigate further with Oracle. I was forced to re-install RAC enviroment from scratch and import schemes (colleagues happily did a backups before any actions).
Currently all is working just fine.